# EGit: Cloning bare remote repository, no master?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, egit

I'm in the process of convincing my team to move to using git for version control (from svn). The major hurdle seems to be convincing them that it's not going to be too complicated for others. To alleviate that, I'm attempting to create clear documentation. I need some help though with Eclipse/EGit, since I'm not as familiar with them. Coming from a Linux background, I always use git from the command line, but this is a Windows shop and asking IT to install git on everyone's machine will be seen as another layer of complexity.

So far the process for starting a new project is logging into the (linux) development server and creating a bare repository in the appropriate directory. The bare repository is (obviously) empty at this point -- so no master branch yet. This is where the question diverges from the others I've seen on SO, and most of the documentation I can find.

My question is what is the best way to clone that bare, empty repository into Eclipse and set it so that it knows to push to origin/master? I can clone it in the Git Repositories view though it seems unhappy that there's no branch. Then I can switch to the appropriate perspective I'm using for development, create the project, then import the git repo, add files, and finally commit and push and it will finally create the master branch. However this seems convoluted. Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As near as I can tell it seems the best way to do this is to first add files to the repository via some other method, then import the git repository to your existing Eclipse project when you can select a branch. That at least gets the git repo in the top level of the Eclipse project, rather than the EGit convention of having the Eclipse project separate (a level beneath) the git repo.